# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'moves'

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to install Ansible, but I can never get a clean install for some reason. using `apt-get install ansible` and then doing a `ansible --version` I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ansible", line 44, in <module>
    import ansible.constants as C
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/constants.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ansible.compat.six import string_types
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/compat/six/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    not hasattr(_system_six.moves, 'shlex_quote') or
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'moves'
```

Comment: What happens if you install Ansible via pip instead? Could be that Debian package is missing a Python dependency somewhere.

Comment: What distro and version are you using?  Are you following [the installation instructions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html)?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I'm currently having problems with pip, but I will report back. It didn't seem to work last time.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov I'm running Trusty Ubuntu via Crouton

Comment: Have you tried [the Ubuntu install instructions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#latest-releases-via-apt-ubuntu)?

Answer (score 0):

Ansible is still very young and OS packaging is lagging behind. Although this particular error may simply be caused by a version mismatch or missing dependency.

May I suggest [running Ansible from source](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_installation.html#running-from-source)?